# How to display data in bubble chart (chart.js) without x and y value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

How to display data in bubble chart (chart.js) without x and y value?

Bubble chart needs data like:

```
datasets: [
    {
      data: [
          {x: 20, y: 20, r: 22, name: '11-550'}
      ],
      backgroundColor: '#1a5da1'
  },
  {
    data: [
        {x: 10, y: 72, r: 10, name: '13-550'}
    ],
    backgroundColor: '#1a5da1'
  }
]
```

Can I display this data without X and Y value?

I want to display it randomly, but without setting it like `x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);` to every 'bubble'